# Attributes showing multiple times (sqlite3/flask)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlite3-python

I ran into some issues with my sqlite3 databank.
I create the db in python and run my flask server in the same file.
In my index.html file I want to show the table as a list.

```
        {% for name in names %}
        <li>{{ name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
```

However this causes some problems. In python I select only the name attribute (I have 2) and they show up in the correct order *but* they repeat. So in the end the list contains 4 times my 2 attributes.

I was able to "fix" this by changing my python code to: `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM my_table`.
But now I added some features. One of them is deleting rows. When I click the delete button it deletes the entry but when I reload the page the exact same one appears. I deleted and reloaded like 7 times and then it's finally gone forever.

This is where I create my db:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inv (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        specific TEXT,
        name TEXT,
        amount REAL,
        place TEXT
    )
''')

cur.executemany('''
    INSERT INTO inv (specific, name, amount, place)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
''', [
    ('220Ohm', 'Resistor', 3, 'Place1'),
    ('400Ohm', 'Resistor', 10, 'Place2'),
    ('5A', 'Switch', 7, 'Place3'),
])

con.commit()
con.close()
```

So i tried to delete and re-created my db. I also tried this "clean-command":

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''
        DELETE FROM inv
        WHERE id NOT IN (
                SELECT MIN(id)
                FROM inv
                GROUP BY specific, name, place
        );
''')
    print('Succsessfully cleaned db')
```

But it didn't change anything.

For calrification: This is what I want my page to look like:

- name1
- name2

But this is how it looks when I remove the DISTINCT command:

- name1
- name2
- name1
- name2
- name1
- name2
- name1
- name2

Comment: your sample wouldn't show your behaviuor https://dbfiddle.uk/Vd1EN8uA

Comment: You have two rows with `name=Resister`. One is 220 Ohm, the other is 400 Ohm.

Comment: So a query that returns all names without using `DISTINCT` will return these duplicates.

Comment: @nbk So then it’s probably a problem with my html code?

Comment: it is hard to tell, as we see only a glimpse, but i would also guess that your display code will be repeated multiple times

Comment: @Barmar Yes it displays the text once but there are still duplicates in the data bank.

Comment: Your "clean code" only removes rows that duplicate all 3 columns.  But `('220Ohm', 'Resistor', 'Place1')` is not a duplicate of `('400Ohm', 'Resistor', 'Place2')` since the speciic and place are different.

Comment: That’s exactly my problem. I have ('220Ohm', 'Resistor', 'Place1') only one time BUT it gets displayed multiple time. Therefore it’s multiple times in the databank. And that’s my problem.